# RVM not changing ruby version on cd (with bash-it)

Tags: bash, terminal, rvm, konsole, bash-it

I've installed `bash-it` recently and I noticed it broken RVM. When I enter a project directory, the ruby version is not changed (not matter if I use `.rvmrc` or `.ruby-version`). However, when I enter a project directory and then open a new tab/window in terminal, ruby version is changed. I tested it in Konsole and Gnome Terminal. I keep `bash-it` configuration in `.bash_profile` and I'm loading it in the end of `.bashrc`. Any ideas for the reason for such a strange behaviour?

EDIT: I tried to start bash as a login shell, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have noticed that bash-it uses unescaped `cd` calls, this could end up in cd'ing into wrong directory and fooling rvms `cd` function ... although there can be number of other problems influencing it, try tracing the `cd` hook with: `( export PS4="+ \${BASH_SOURCE##\${rvm_path:-}} : \${FUNCNAME[0]:+\${FUNCNAME[0]}()}  \${LINENO} > "; set -x ; cd project )`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I disabled some of bash-it plugins and it works again. I suspect, that it was `fastd` that broke rvm.